# Grails running incorrect source code

Tags: grails, groovy, sublimetext2

I'm trying to build a simple grails application to get to know the framework. I tried to put a size constraint on a String field by doing this:

```
name size: 4...18, blank: false, unique: true
```

The triple dot means an inclusive range in ruby and I didn't know that it doesn't work in groovy. When I tried to do a generate-all on the domain class. Grails says that there is an unexpected token on the ... so I tried to edit my code to look like this:

```
name size: 4..19, blank: false, unique: true
```

When I try to do a generate-all it still says that my code looks like the first one. I tried clean, clean-all, restarting the grails environment, restarting sublime, and deleting all the constraints.

Any ideas why this is happening?

Comment: Captain Obvious here, the first row says 4...18 (there should only be two dots) but the second line looks alright. Can't say I've seen it.

Comment: Yeah. I did the three dots since that's how ruby does it. I've since edited my code to two dots but it still sees the tree dots. I rebooted my pc and it now works fine. I have no idea why it borked though.

Comment: @AkoEliasLopezlopezlopezLopez Maybe delete this question?

Comment: I was hoping someone could tell me why grails needs me to restart my system every once in a while. It happened again. I was trying to do a generate-all but the errors wouldn't go away until I rebooted. Although I'm not sure if maybe sublime might be responsible somehow.

Comment: how do you run the code?  ``grails run-app``?  when you run your app (see reloading questions here) and save a groovy file you should see something like ``Compiling N source files`` in the grails shell (yet it might fail with doamin classes to work).

Comment: I run run-app while inside the grails environment if that's significant. Every time I change something in the file. It says compiling. Anyway it hasn't happened again so I'll close this question in a few days. I'm still hoping someone can answer why it happened.